# Does re-deploying kubernetes statefulset preserve persistent volume claim?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-zookeeper, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

We have a kubernetes statefulset with a persistent volume claim for storage class "zookeeper"

There are 6 persistent volumes of storage class "zookeeper"

The deployment is done using a Helm chart. When I first install the helm chart with 3 replica count, the statefulset uses say, Pv1,Pv2 and Pv3. All running ok.

Delete purge the helm chart.

Re-install the same Helm chart with same number of replicas, 3
This time will the statefulset chose the same Persistent volumes, Pv1, Pv2 and Pv3 or will it choose any random Pv's from the 6 Pv's.
This is important because across deployments, if the persistent volume changes, the zookeeper "myid" is messed-up.

Comment: Is your `StatefulSet` making the claim or you do it separately?

Answer (score 3):

StatefulSet provides a key named as `volumeClaimTemplates` using that, you can request the PVC from the storage class dynamically. The `volumeClaimTemplates` will provide stable storage using PersistentVolumes provisioned by a PersistentVolume Provisioner.

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
- metadata:
    name: my-pv
  spec:
    accessModes: 
      - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 1Gi
```

When you have multiple replica, you will see the pods are created one by one sequentially, and the PVC is requested during the pod creation.The PVC naming is combination of  `volumeClaimTemplate name + pod-name + order number`.

For example, we will have the following PVCs naming

```
my-pv-app-0
my-pv-app-1
.. and so on
```

The volume is mount to the respective pod in order there after any restart by scaling operation on  StatefulSet will not delete the volumes associated with the StatefulSet.